# Difference between application.haml and application.html.haml?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, haml, ujs

Since many days I tried to understand why a simple link like this one :

```
link_to 'My Link', my_path(format: :js), remote: true
```

was always returning full HTML document instead of executing javascript located in my file.js.erb :

```
alert('hello world')
```

[...]

After hours of debugging I found why:

When **I rename my main layout file such as**: `application.haml` it renders full HTML document :

```
Started GET "/my_path/2.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-05 12:28:20 +0100
Processing by MyController#show as JS
  Rendered my_path/show.js.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_sidebar.html.erb (18.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_headbar.haml (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.haml (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 102ms (Views: 59.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
```

When **I rename my main layout file such as**: `application.html.haml` it executes javascript properly and runs my *hello world popup* :

```
Started GET "/my_path/8.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-05 12:28:34 +0100
Processing by MyController#show as JS
  Rendered my_path/show.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 21.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

**Why is there a difference in the javascript behavior according the different filenames of my layout ?**

Comment: This is not javascript behaviour, it is how rails searches for templates. First it search for `<action_name>.<templating-engine>` files, then for `<action_name>.<format><templateing-engine>`. So when you have generic template without the format, it will be taken for all the formats.

Comment: If one of view template is missing for a action, rails shall report error which tells how it is searching for it including the path, format, etc. With such info, you will know the search order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BroiSatse said:

> This is not javascript behaviour, it is how rails searches for
>   templates. First it search for `<action_name>.<templating-engine>`
>   files, then for `<action_name>.<format><templateing-engine>`. So when
>   you have generic template without the format, it will be taken for all
>   the formats.